# Dynamically set socat container IP address in Jenkins Docker Host URI

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I deploy a Docker stack (`docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml stackname`) made up of two Docker services: Jenkins and socat.
However, configuring A Docker Cloud Agent on Jenkins dashboard, I manually provide in 'Docker Host URI' field the socat container IP with its 2375 port (tcp://socat_container_ip:2375), because I need this port that is mapped to my Docker host, this works fine.

[The Docker Host Uri field in Jenkins dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmGH7.png)

Obviously, I can only provide the right IP after I have deployed the stack and checked the socat container IP, this is cumbersome.

How can I do this automatically in the same moment I run `docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml stackname`? I thought of static IP, or environment variable, the latter seems the best to me.

.

Update:

if I click on info ('?' symbol) next to the Docker Host URI field it shows "URI to the Docker Host you are using. May be left blank to use the Docker default (defined by DOCKER_HOST environment variable)". So I left the Docker Host URI field blank, and wrote my Docker compose file this way:

```
version: '3'

services:

  socat:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: "tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock"
    cap_drop:
      - cap_dac_override
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        delay: 2s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 3s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 60s
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - network_jenkins
    ports:
      - 2376:2375

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17
    cap_drop:
      - cap_dac_override
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        delay: 2s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 3s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 60s
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Rome
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://socat:2375
    depends_on:
      - socat
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - network_jenkins
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    external: true

networks:
  network_jenkins:
    external: true
```

But it didn't work, as in the container logs it shows "INFO c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-cloud-agent". Note the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in Jenkins service...